# Are the eigenvectors of the Choi-Jamiolkowski state maximally entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, trace

Let $\phi: M_n\rightarrow M_n$ be a quantum channel (completely positive trace preserving). Via the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism we can transform this into a state

$$J(\phi) = (I_n\otimes\phi)(M) = \sum_{ij}E_{ij}\otimes\phi(E_{ij})$$
where $M$ denotes the maximally entangled state and $E_{ij}$ the matrix with a 1 at the $ij$ position and zero's everywhere else.

This state is positive definite if and only if $\phi$ is completely positive. This means that it has an eigenvalue decomposition:
$$J(\phi) = \sum_i \lambda_i P_i$$
for some 1-dimensional projections $P_i\in M_n\otimes M_n$. These projections can be called maximally entangled when Tr$_1(P_i) = I_n$ and Tr$_2(P_i) = I_n$.

Can the $P_i$ be chosen such that they all are maximally entangled?

I know this is true when $\phi$ is a unitary conjugation and when $n=2$. Is it true in general?

Comment: Did you try a few examples?

Comment: Guess you didn't ...

Comment: I have checked it for the depolarizing maps, for which it is true. I don't know for any others. Are you implying that there is an easy counter-example? If so, could you point me towards it?

Comment: Just posted an answer.  In fact, I am right now thinking about posting a canonical "which (counter)examples for channels should I check" question/answer.  A few come to mind: Depolarizing, dephasing, "discard + make a new state" (the example below), the Holevo-Werner channel, entanglement-breaking channels.  If it's true for all of those, it's probably a theorem.

Comment: Such an answer would definitely be helpful for me at least, especially since the definitions of these channels are scattered all over the place.

Comment: Related: [What's the intuition behind the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270032/whats-the-intuition-behind-the-choi-jamiolkowski-isomorphism)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch That sounds like a particularly useful Q&A, please do write it. I'm looking for good questions to sink some rep into, if it'll help ;-).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Here you go: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291810/canonical-examples-of-quantum-channels/   BTW, my first question here ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

A simple counterexample is the qubit channel
$$
\phi:\rho\mapsto \mathrm{tr}(\rho)|0\rangle\langle0|\ .
$$
Its Choi state is $J(\phi)=\tfrac12\mathbb{I}\otimes |0\rangle\langle0|$,
whose eigenvalue decomposition satisfies $\mathrm{tr}_1(P_i)=|0\rangle\langle0|$.

EDIT: I have now compiled a [list of canonical examples to check.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291810/canonical-examples-of-quantum-channels/)

Comment: Is there also an easy example of a unital such map? I guess some entanglement-breaking channels would do right?

Comment: Any unital channel that is not a convex combination of unitary conjugations will provide a unital counter-example. The Werner-Holevo channels for odd $d\geq 3$ are specific examples.