# Existence conditions for completely positive trace-preserving (CPTP) map

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

Given two separable Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$, I am wondering: what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for there to be a completely positive trace-preserving (CPTP) map $\Phi:B(\mathcal{H}_1)\to B(\mathcal{H}_2)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The map $\Phi(\rho) = \mathrm{tr}(\rho)\sigma$, for some state $\sigma\in B(\mathcal H_2)$ with $\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)=1$ is CPTP and  exists for any pair of separable Hilbert spaces.

(As always for these questions, let me advertise my [list of canonical examples for quantum channels](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291810/canonical-examples-of-quantum-channels/291811).)